# Parameterization by arc length

Tags: curves, parametrization, arc-length

What happens if you reparameterized by arc length a curve that is already parameterized by arc length?

I just did it because I didn't read the statement right.

Comment: What are you talking about? Please provide more context.

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco a curve in space, is differential geometry

Comment: It's funny because it's not equivalent, if you put any number in it, it's not the same to you. Then if such a step procedure, the "reparameterization" was done correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You get back the same parameter, because if $\gamma$ is a curve already parametrized by arc-length, say, $s$, then $\|\gamma'(s)\|=1$ for every $s$, hence
$$p(s)=\int_0^{s}\|\gamma'(\sigma)\|\,d\sigma=s,$$
so the "new" parameterization by arc-length $p(s)$ is precisely the previous one, $s$.

Comment: If you construct an arc length parameterization from a parameterization that is already one, then that is what we both say, that only changes the name of the parameter in any case, that is, that nothing changes.

But you can have two different settings for the same curve, and if for each one you calculate the setting for the arc length, you will have different ones.

Comment: @yse65051 - Can you please provide an example illustrating your argument?

Answer (score 1):

Without loss of generality, suppose the curve $\ C \ $is a finite or infinite interval of real numbers. An arc length parametrization of $\ C \ $ is a bijection $\ f: I \to C \ $ where $\ I \ $ is also a finite or infinite interval of real numbers and such that
 $\ \forall x\in I \ $ then $\ |f'(x)| = 1. \ $ Any such function is of the form $\ f(x) = c \pm x \ $ where the constant $\ c \ $ and sign $\ \pm \ $ are such that endpoints get mapped to endpoints.

In the general case, where there are two arc length parametrizations of a curve, the composition of one of them followed by the inverse of the other reduces to the special case described above.